# DOMPDF images not showing on new server

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I've created an application which outputs a PDF report based on an HTML page using DOMPDF.

This works fine on my test server, but when I've migrated it over to the live server, none of the images show in the PDF.  It's not showing a RED X - just nothing there at all.

I've checked that the new server meets the requirements using the config tool, and I've enabled the "leave images in temp" debugging option, and nothing is being created in the the temp directory.

Any ideas what might have changed to stop it from working?

Comment: Turn on full PHP error reporting, report back.

Comment: Add this to the top of your code:

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: Ok done that, and there are no errors showing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that if your CSS specifies your images as display:block, DOMPDF won't show them sometimes.  Have changed my code so that it uses a pdf-specific CSS file without that it.

No idea why it worked on the other server though....

Comment: This makes sense as the default display property for the img element is [-dompdf-image](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/source/browse/trunk/dompdf/lib/res/html.css?r=456#414). Changing the display would appear to alter dompdf's ability to recognize that the element is, in fact, and image.

Answer (score 3):

Note: For windows servers I had to point the true path to the images:

```
<img src="C:\path\to\image\folder\image.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I am on linux though. I had to mention the full path of the image.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too. On the local server i could use for the image

`<img src="www.test.dev/img/test.jpg" />` ,

but on the live server i had to change it to

`<img src="img/test.jpg" />`.

In this way you force dompdf on the server to locally access the image file.

Comment: i am doing the same as you mentioned (<img src="pathToImages/name.png">), but it gives me error 'Image not readable or empty'

Comment: if you've got this message, it's because the path you wrote is wrong