# dompdf image not found on live server

Tags: php, css, tinymce, dompdf

After several hours of searching, I am still unable to resolve this issue. I am having a problem with displaying images in a PDF file generated by [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) library.

I have an editor [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php) where a user can upload images, edit his page, and see a preview in PDF format with a Button press.

**One important thing here:** I am using 'convert_urls : true' in tinyMCE's configuration which converts the image src = "https://mysite.com/public/images/image_name.png", necessary for the PDF library to display them.

I set the required dompdf configurations:

- def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", true);

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996687/dompdf-images-not-showing-on-new-server) I found that it will appear after changing the attached CSS with a dompdf like:

```
img { display:block }
```

All still in vain.

**Note:** Everything is working fine on localhost. But on the staging server, I get a message box having a cross inside it saying "image not found" and displaying the image path. When I click on that path, the image is already there on my server. I wonder why dompdf is giving me this message?

Comment: Are you sure you can access the image without any authentication?

Comment: Also, make sure your server allows URLs in file open processes (allow_url_fopen = true). If you're using v0.6.x you can check dompdf/www/setup.php to see if there are any issues with your installation. For a more complete list of relevant settings see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14328719/264628.

Comment: I answered [HERE][1] which solved my problem as well as others !!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153139/dompdf-remote-image-is-not-displaying-in-pdf/23168716?noredirect=1#comment38498967_23168716

Comment: DOMPDF doesn't appear to handle remote images over `https`

Answer (score 9):

I already faced same kind of issue. solution is very simple when Dompdf does not accept url with http format. Try with full document root.

Instead of using https://example.com/public/images/image_name.png try with /var/www/mysite/public/images/image_name.png

Comment: To clarify, Dompdf can handle web-based image and CSS references just fine. You just have to ensure that your system meets the [minimum requirements](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Use a absolute path for external css and images than live path! its worked for me also